# How to get page title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, page-title

Well, I have tried 
`<?php echo get_the_title('About Us');?>`

But the code is not working. I am using wordpress 4.1. This should work but it isn't. Has wordpress updated the functions?

Comment: Try `global $post; echo $post->post_title`

Answer (score 36):

Try this one, It's may help you

```
<?php single_post_title(); ?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: In my case, I was using `the_title()` on index.php resulting in the most recent post title being the page title instead of the page title. Your solution resolves this.

Comment: How to get the parent element for nested page liks parent_page => sub_page I want to get this parent_page/sub_page

Answer (score 15):

Try this one,may it's help you

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

And if you want to get page or post title By id

```
 <?php echo get_the_title(post->$ID); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use `the_title()` to display the title of the page. You can pass parameters for before and after HTML tags. For morr information, here are the docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/

```
<?php

the_title();

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are giving wrong parameters to `get_title`. See the [`codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title#Parameters).

You should have used `ID` instead to get the title.

So your code would be

```
 <?php echo get_the_title(13); //where 13 is the ID of the about us page ?>
```

**NOTE:** Parameters are optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 <?php echo get_page_by_title( 'About' ); ?>
```

[**Reference**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $page = get_page_by_title( 'About Us' );
 echo get_the_title($page->ID)
?>
```