# get the current page title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and have been trying figure out things on my own.

I’m trying to get the title of the current page I’m in (front-page.page).

I’m using `the_title();` but I don’t get any results.

Also I'm using wordpress version 5.5.3.

Any idea what I need to use?

Comment: use `get_the_title()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get page title in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653694/how-to-get-page-title-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_title()` insted of the_title()

if you are unable to get title, then try passing the page id as argument like

`get_the_title(1)` Where 1 is id of current page. you can get the page id
from wp-admin -> pages -> your current page -> in the address bar it will display something like "yoursite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1" where 1 is your page id.

Comment: I have used `get_the_title()` and `get_the_title(page ID)` as well as you said.but it doesn't going well.anyway thank you

Comment: `$page = get_page_by_title( 'Home' ); echo get_the_title($page->ID) ;` First I used as you said.Then I found the way like this and I do not know I'm right or wrong.But it does work.

Comment: May be you were providing the wrong id. bcz what are you doing is getting id from page and then fetching the title using that id.